# Pass multidimensional array to Oracle stored procedure

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, oci8

I have SP with custom type:

```
Create Or Replace Type tyTestArrayType As Object
    (siF1 SmallInt,
    siF2 SmallInt,
    siF3 SmallInt);


Create Or Replace Type tyTestArray Is Table Of tyTestArrayType;

Create Or Replace Procedure prTestArray(pArr tyTestArray,
                                        pResult In Out SmallInt)

Is
Begin

    pResult := 0;

    For I In 1..pArr.Count
    Loop
        pResult := pResult + pArr(I).siF1 + pArr(I).siF2 + pArr(I).siF3;
    End Loop;

End;
```

How can I use this procedure (pass multidimensional array) from PHP (oci8)?

Thanks,

Update:

This is a code performing this in Ruby:

```
plsql.connection = OCI8.new("user","pass","host/XE")
testArray =  [{:sif1 => 1, :sif2 => 12, :sif3=>4},{:sif1 => 5, :sif2 => 2, :sif3=>3}]
puts plsql.prTestArray(p_testArray,0) #=> {:presult=>27}
```

Comment: This array has one dimension, so it is not multidimensional.

Comment: Yes, but I need to pass array of tyTestArrayTypes:      

pArr = array(tyTestArrayType,tyTestArrayType,tyTestArrayType...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have developped an identical stored procedure (using Table of ...) as input and it was difficult to be called from Java code. So I switched to a CLOB input and passed an XML from code. 
In XML you can have an array as multi-dimensional as you wish and it is very easy to build a XML string in PHP.

XML parsing is made easy with ORACLE:

CLOB:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DATA>
     <LINE>
        <COD_NOMCPDT>040001</COD_NOMCPDT>
     </LINE>

     <LINE>
        <COD_NOMCPDT>040002</COD_NOMCPDT>        
     </LINE>    
</DATA>
```

Query:

```
SELECT
extractvalue(column_value, '/LINE/COD_NOMCPDT')
  FROM TABLE(XMLSequence(XMLTYPE(
               CLOB_VARIABLE).extract('/DATA/LINE'))) );
```

Output:

```
040001
040002
```

Another option would be to store the array in a temporary table and read it from there (no IN parameters).